# parList vs parTraversable

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I found a "strange" behavior here. I got this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.List
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main =
  let xs = [ fib (20 + n `mod` 2) | n <- [0..1000] ]
              `using` test rseq
   in print (sum xs)

test :: Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
test strat xs = do
  parTraversable strat xs  -- case #1
  -- parList strat xs      -- case #2
  return xs
```

`case #1` means using `parTraversable`, `case #2` means using `parList`. The results are different:

```
case #1: SPARKS: 1001 (1 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 1000 GC'd, 0 fizzled)
case #2: SPARKS: 1001 (1000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1 fizzled)
```

As far as I know, `parList` is the same as `parTraversable`. In `Control/Parallel/Strategies.hs`:

```
parTraversable :: Traversable t => Strategy a -> Strategy (t a)
parTraversable strat = evalTraversable (rparWith strat)

parList :: Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
parList = parTraversable
```

So I supposed they have to act the same. Anything need to be uncover here?

**Update #1**:

Commands to compile and run:

```
stack ghc -- -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -eventlog parlist2.hs
./parList2 +RTS -N2 -s
```

Comment: How were they compiled and run? Please show full command lines.